# Is there a way to include Soft Assert in Postman tests?

Tags: postman, assert, web-api-testing

So that it should not stop the deployment in Pipeline if any of the tests fail.

[image: Refer the screenshot to view the Status]

Comment: Why have tests in place if you're just wanting to bypass them? If the test isn't giving you the information you need or providing any value, why is it even there? Your assertion is going to be a yes/no answer, what would a 'soft assertion' look like? Logging something to the console instead?

Comment: @DannyDainton, thanks for the reply, and yes, I want to know the status of a request. If the status is not as expected, then wanted to know the current status.

Comment: How do you define 'status'?

Comment: @DannyDainton, I've edited the post. Please refer the screenshot.

1. The status shown in the picture could be "In progress, "Completed" or "Failed". 
2. I'll need to assert it to "Completed" but the tests should not fail if I get either of other statuses. However, in the pipeline I need to know what is the status.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, soft assertions with a test are not possible at the moment in Postman tests.

However, an alternative is to simply split the tests up into different tests.

This:

```js
pm.test('Status code is 201', () => {
    pm.response.to.have.status(201);
});

const json = pm.response.json();

pm.test('Idea External Id is present', () => {
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('external_id')
        .to.have.lengthOf(16);

    pm.environment.set("idea-external-id", json.external_id);
});

pm.test('Expected Idea is returned', () => {
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('title', 'Make Bed $0.50');
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('description', 'Make your bed.');
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.nested.property('call_to_action.uri', 'https://youtu.be/Du0M6yVjKlA');
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.nested.property('call_to_action.label', 'Instructional Video');
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('key', 'chore_chart');
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('created_at');
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('updated_at');
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.nested.property('_links.self.href')
        .to.match(new RegExp(`.+/idea/${pm.environment.get("idea-external-id")}`));
});
```

Becomes this:

```js
pm.test('Status code is 201', () => {
    pm.response.to.have.status(201);
});

const json = pm.response.json();

pm.test('Idea External Id is present', () => {
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('external_id')
        .to.have.lengthOf(16);

    pm.environment.set("idea-external-id", json.external_id);
});

pm.test('Expected Idea title is returned', () => {
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('title', 'Make Bed $0.50');
});

pm.test('Expected Idea description is returned', () => {
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('description', 'Make your bed.');
});

pm.test('Expected Idea call_to_action.uri is returned', () => {
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.nested.property('call_to_action.uri', 'https://youtu.be/Du0M6yVjKlA');
});

pm.test('Expected Idea call_to_action.uri is returned', () => {
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.nested.property('call_to_action.label', 'Instructional Video');
});

pm.test('Expected Idea key is returned', () => {
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('key', 'chore_chart');
});

pm.test('Idea created_at is returned', () => {
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('created_at');
});

pm.test('Idea updated_at is returned', () => {
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.property('updated_at');
});

pm.test('Expected Idea _links is returned', () => {
    pm.expect(json)
        .to.have.nested.property('_links.self.href')
        .to.match(new RegExp(`.+/idea/${pm.environment.get("idea-external-id")}`));
});
```